# Is it performant to keep a ref on all children in a list?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, performance, dom

I want to make a list of children that are `position: absolute;` and for the container height to be calculated based on the height of all children + padding. We can assume that all children are the same size.

```
const ChildItem = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <a ref={ref} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: props.index * 30 + 'px' }}>
            child
        </a>
    );
});

class HeightTest extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            height: 0,
        };
        this.childElem = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Measure the height of one child
        this.setState({ height: this.childElem.current.offsetHeight });
    }

    render() {
        const items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        const PADDING = 20;
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    position: 'relative',
                    padding: PADDING,
                    height: 2 * PADDING + this.state.height * items.length + 'px',
                }}
            >
                {items.map(item => {
                    return <ChildItem ref={this.childElem} index={item} key={item} />;
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Technically i only need to measure the height of one `ChildItem`, but right now we're passing the `ref` to all. Is this performant, or is there a better way to do this?

Ideally we could just say 'measure the height of all of the items, and set the container height to that' instead of multiplying by `items.length`

thanks in advance

Comment: You can pass height as a prop to children and apply it to style the same you do with props.index

Comment: But i want the height to be _based_ on the children, not to tell the children how high to be. So I want to set the height of the container based on (childheight * number children)

Comment: Oh, I got it, sorry. I think the correct way is to solve your problem via styles (css). Usually div stretches to its children height

Comment: Yep - except for this case where the elements are `position: absolute;` - which is something I need for this case

Comment: Do do you really need an absolute positioning? Maybe there's a way to use another styling? I see you're trying to set 'top' coordinate  base on child item index. Maybe you can use margin-top or padding-top instead of absolute positioning?

Comment: Nope it's because we need to slide-in the new items (it's a drilldown). I've tried very much to avoid absolute positioning